# DevExpress Export to PDF Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, viewmodel, nullreferenceexception

I have an issue with the ExportToPdf function from the GridViewExtension class of DevExpress. When my code reaches this block,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportTo(int Year, string Id, int CaseNumber)
{
    _SvcM = new SvcViewModels();
    List<SomeViewmodel> data = _SvcM.GetSomeModelData(Year, Id, CaseNumber);
    GridViewSettings settings = GetGridSettings();
    ViewBag.GridSettings = settings;
    return GridViewExtension.ExportToPdf(settings, data);
}
```

the program throws a NullReferenceException on the last line of the Action method. I have debugged the input values and made sure they are of the correct type and not null. The data object is an Enumerated List which is populated through the `GetSomeModelData` method. I have no idea why the Export method can't execute properly, does anybody have any clue?

Comment: what type does ExportToPdf returns ? Is it compatible with ActionResult ?

Comment: ExportToPdf returns an ActionResult in the form of a download of the pdf file. I do a POST-request to the action from my view, which lets me download the pdf file without leaving the page. The ExportTo() action does not have a View for this reason.

Comment: Your `data` variable passed to `ExportToPdf` method may contains `List<SomeViewmodel>` which has null reference due to effect from `GetSomeModelData` method (probably fetched from database and returning no available results), thus it throws NRE. Can you show the logic inside `GetSomeModelData` method there?